# Adding XmlNode into XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml

I've got some xml node that I've pulled out and I'm using XmlWriter to create the relevant Xml file.

The XmlNode needs to go inside   but I wasn't sure how to use the XmlNode to create the Elements inside.

**Xml Format as below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tasks>
   <task Id="113" Date="2013-03-12T13:55:09" NodeId="1842" TotalWords="11">

   </task>
</tasks>
```

**XmlWriter codes**

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(MapPath(xmlFilePath)))
                {

                    writer.WriteStartDocument();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Tasks");

                    writer.WriteStartElement("Task");
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("Id", t.Id.ToString());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("NodeId", t.Node.Id.ToString());

                    // The XmlNode needs to be inside here //

                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndDocument();


                }
```

**Details of the XmlNode that I've pulled out**

```
<Page id="1842" parentID="1840" level="5" writerID="14" creatorID="14" nodeType="1051" template="1839" sortOrder="0" createDate="2013-03-11T14:53:47" updateDate="2013-03-12T14:03:55" nodeName="Ujian sub-halaman" urlName="ujian-sub-halaman" writerName="John John" creatorName="John John" path="-1,1057,1631,1156,1840,1842" isDoc="">
         <pageContent />
         <heroHeaderImage />
         <topModule>-1</topModule>
         <bottomModule>-1</bottomModule>
         <rHTopModule />
         <headerQuickLinks>
            <data />
         </headerQuickLinks>
         <rHBottomModule>-1</rHBottomModule>
         <pageTitle>Ujian sub-halaman</pageTitle>
         <umbracoNaviHide>0</umbracoNaviHide>
         <pageHeader><![CDATA[Test sub-page]]></pageHeader>
         <showAddThis>0</showAddThis>
         <alternativeTitle>Test sub-page</alternativeTitle>
         <smallPrint>0</smallPrint>
         <pageImage />
         <siteName />
         <metaDescription />
         <metaKeywords />
         <metaCopyright />
         <defaultEmail />
         <googleUrchin />
         <facebook />
         <googlePlus />
         <linkedIn />
         <twitter />
         <youtube />
      </Page>
```

Comment: LINQ to XML is much easier to use than XmlWriter.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but assuming you have an XmlNode - let's call it `the_node` then you could just use the [WriteRaw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0755ytay.aspx) method of XmlWriter to embed the markup of the node into the output stream of `writer`.

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(MapPath(xmlFilePath)))
{

   writer.WriteStartDocument();
   writer.WriteStartElement("Tasks");

   writer.WriteStartElement("Task");
   writer.WriteAttributeString("Id", t.Id.ToString());
   writer.WriteAttributeString("NodeId", t.Node.Id.ToString());

  // The XmlNode needs to be inside here //
   writer.WriteRaw(the_node.OuterXml);

   writer.WriteEndElement();

   writer.WriteEndElement();
   writer.WriteEndDocument();


}
```

Comment: I recomment to use "the_node.WriteTo(writer)" instead of "writer.WriteRaw(the_node.OuterXml)".

Comment: @Frankenstein Why?

Comment: @NisimNaim WriteTo will verify the submitted xml code before it will be written. In contrast WriteRaw will skip this step. In this example the OuterXml of a node is always correct. But with other data you might risk writing invalid xml code